# Custom OS Version-ing

Tags: centos, version

I made a custom centos by following the link given below

[https://github.com/joyent/mi-centos-7](http://github.com/joyent/mi-centos-7)

Now I want to add my own version to the ISO file so that it shows when we check it using the following command

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

How can I add my own version to the custom ISO?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to enter custom information into that file. 
Write your own version for that file and put into /etc/os-release.

after that you should be able to do

`cat /etc/os-release`

If you just wasnt to change the name of your OS and not change any other release information, you should try changing the name in the
[isolinux.cfg](https://github.com/joyent/mi-centos-7/blob/master/isolinux.cfg) file. 
Do this change locally and try building the OS again. Then try in a VM if it worked.

**Update:** Since the method didn't work as per your requirements, I have made some changes to the code itself. 
Could you try with this code repo [mi-centos-7 modified by libregeekingkid](https://github.com/rajuvindane/mi-centos-7)
If you need to make more changes to the os-release file content, modify the OS-release file in the folder.

Comment: I just realized this is not what I want to do. I need to make changes that when someone else installs it and runs that command then it shows my version.

Comment: @SudhanshAggarwal yes, that's what will happen if you edit the file.

Comment: @terdon I made these changes to this after installing the ISO on a VM. Are you saying that I can make these changes in the ISO file itself, so that whoever installs this can see the custom version?

Comment: @AgentWeirdo yes, precisely.

Comment: @AgentWeirdo I am taking a look at the source in the link that you gave. Give me a few minutes and I'll edit my answer according to that.

Comment: @AgentWeirdo Could you give me the output of 'cat /etc/os-release' ? I just want to see what exactly is it showing now. Also tell me, do you just want to change the name of the distro or any other information as well?

Comment: output is the same as what we get here linuxconfig.org/how-to-check-centos-version

Comment: @terdon Where in the ISO do I make the changes?

Comment: You make changes in the file I mentioned in my answer. And your ISO should have your name. No need to manually open and edit files in the ISO.

Comment: @libregeekingkid sorry I missed that while reading it earlier. I'll try it now.

Comment: @AgentWeirdo Any luck?

Comment: @libregeekingkid I made a couple of changes to the lines that begin with "Append". That did not solve my query.
Could you tell me where in isolinux.cfg do I make the changes?

Comment: @AgentWeirdo In this file, put the name of your OS in front of LABEL= Make no changes to append. that might cause problems

Comment: @libregeekingkid Thats what I did. Sorry for not mentioning it earlier.

Comment: @AgentWeirdo Did you try rebuilding the ISO then?

Comment: @libregeekingkid Yes. the name is changing. But  when I read /etc/os-release then the output is still the default one.

Comment: ohk, give me a few minutes @AgentWeirdo , I'll give you another procedure.

Comment: @AgentWeirdo See the updated answer. Try creating the OS from my repo and let me know if it worked.

Comment: @libregeekingkid sudo ./create_iso layout isn't working. It is facing the following problem. "cp: cannot create regular file `/data/centos-7-iso-layout/etc/os-release': No such file or directory"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38381/discussion-between-agentweirdo-and-libregeekingkid).